# Using Rcpp function in parLapply on Windows

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp

I'm doing R code optimization with Rcpp and parallel computing on Windows. I have a trouble calling Rcpp function in parLapply. The example is following

Rcpp code (test.cpp)

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector payoff( double strike, NumericVector data) {
    return pmax(data - strike, 0);
}
```

R code

```
library(parallel)
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp("test.cpp")

strike_list <- as.list(seq(10, 100, by = 5))

data <- runif(10000) * 50

# One core version
strike_payoff <- lapply(strike_list, payoff, data)

# Multiple cores version
numWorkers <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(numWorkers, type = "PSOCK")
clusterExport(cl = cl,varlist = "payoff")
strike_payoff <- parLapply(cl, strike_list, payoff, data)
```

Error for parallel version

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  8 nodes produced errors; first error: NULL value passed as symbol address
```

I know that this is a Windows issue, as mclapply works well on Linux, but I don't have as powerful Linux machine as with Windows.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Please clarify: You run the code on a win machine and the server is also a win machine?

Comment: I have only local Windows machine. No server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run the `sourceCpp()` call in each spawned process, or else get them your code.   Right now the main process has the function, the spawned workers do not.

Easiest way is by building a package and have it loaded by each worker process.

Comment: But sourceCpp() is relatively slow. I haven't done package building. Do you think it would be faster to build package once and load it to each worker?

Comment: Yes, that is how building a package works. You only compile once.