# Using Rcpp functions inside of R's par*apply functions from the parallel package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp

I'm trying to understand what is happening behind the `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` call on a parallelized environment. Recently, this was partially addressed in the question: [Using Rcpp function in parLapply on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606733/using-rcpp-function-in-parlapply-on-windows/25606950).

Within this post, Dirk said,

> "You need to run the sourceCpp() call in each spawned process, or else get them your code."

This was in response to questioner's use of distributing the *Rcpp* function to the worker processes. The questioner was sending the *Rcpp* function via:

```
clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = "payoff")
```

I'm confused as to why this doesn't work. My thoughts are that this was what the objective of the `clusterExport()` is for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that the compiled code is not "exportable" to the spawned processes without being embedded in a package due to how binaries are linked into *R*'s processes.

Traditionally, the `clusterExport()` statement allows for *R* specific code to be distributed to workers.

By using `clusterExport()` on an Rcpp function, you are only receiving the *R* declaration and **not** the underlying shared library. That is to say, the `R CMD SHLIB` given in [Attributes.R](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/ca82a84e892bb6f825d3a4cbde380092caba6425/R/Attributes.R#L122-L136) is not shared with / exported to the workers. As a result, when a call is then made to an `Rcpp` function on the worker, *R* cannot find the correct shared library.

Take the previous question's function:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector payoff( double strike, NumericVector data) {
    return pmax(data - strike, 0);
}")
```

**Note:** I'm using `cppFunction()` instead of `sourceCpp()` but the results are **equivalent** since [`cppFunction()` calls `sourceCpp()` to create the function](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/ca82a84e892bb6f825d3a4cbde380092caba6425/R/Attributes.R#L295-L300).

Typing the function name:

```
payoff
```

Yields the *R* declaration with a shared library pointer.

```
function (strike, data) 
.Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: 0x1015ec130>, strike, data)
```

This shared library is only available on process that **compiled** the function.

Hence, why it is always ideal to embed compiled code within a package and then distribute the package.

Comment: So, if I add my one .cpp file to a package, and export it to the workers using clusterEvalQ it should resolve my issue?

Comment: Yup, as the package handles the wrapping of the compiled code.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'm starting to look around for easy ways of making a package with a single file. Do you have a recommended resource?

Comment: I accepted the answer, and tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Plenty of examples of making a package with a single file in my tutorial slides.  Start from `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`, preferably with pkgKitten installed, or use the package skeleton generator built into RStudio (and select "Package w/Rcpp").  Because each time you create a package using devtools $DEITY kills a kitten.  Just kidding.  Nice answer otherwise and to the (very important) point. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the advice you two! I was able to create my package using this link http://web.mit.edu/insong/www/pdf/rpackage_instructions.pdf. When I have more time I'll definitely give your book a read through Dirk!