# Combine Rcpp, parLapply (parallel), and build a package with package.skeleton

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp

I am running a code using the parallel package and I would like to include the c++ implementation of a part of this code using Rcpp. It seems that the question has been partially addressed:

1. here: [Using Rcpp function in parLapply on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606733/using-rcpp-function-in-parlapply-on-windows)
2. and here: [Using Rcpp functions inside of R's par*apply functions from the parallel package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518387/using-rcpp-functions-inside-of-rs-parapply-functions-from-the-parallel-package)
3. and in many other forums

Apparently, the optimal solution would be to include the c++ implementation into a package, build it, and export the function from the package.

The following are the steps that I took and I present them in a simplified version of the original code, so that anyone can reproduce it. I am working in Windows.

First, let's define the c++ implementation.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <math.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

NumericVector add(NumericVector x, NumericVector y)
{
  return (x+y);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f_sample_p(
    NumericVector x, 
    int nb = 5
)
{
  NumericVector x1;
  NumericVector x2;
  
  // new sample 
  x1 = sample(x, nb, true);
  x2 = sample(x, nb, true);
  
  return add(x1, x2);
}
```

The code contains two functions: one named `add` that is not exported to R and one named `f_sample_p` that uses `add` and is exported to R. This example code will generate a random sample  in a fancy way given an input vector. The structure of the original code is similar in which I cannot pack everything in a single function.

As a second step, I build the package using `Rcpp.package.skeleton` in a user-defined path.

```
library(Rcpp)

cpp_src_path <- "~/R/rcpp/sample_p.cpp" # where I store the c++ implementation

dest_path_of_pkg <- "~/R/rpkg/" # where I want to build the skeleton

Rcpp.package.skeleton(name = "mypkg", # the name of the package
                      list = character(), # I suppose I have to leave like this?
                      path = dest_path_of_pkg, # here I set the path
                      force = T, 
                      code_files = character(), # because I don't have any R codes
                      cpp_files = cpp_src_path, # set the cpp source
                      example_code = F, attributes = F, module = F
                      )

# if I set attributes = FALSE then I have to compile the attributes
compileAttributes("~/R/rpkg/mypkg", TRUE)
```

I let the parameter `list` empty because if I set it to `"f_sample_p"` it will not work. Also I am not sure about all other parameters. Yet, it works and creates the skeleton. However, I have to manually edit the file NAMESPACE and change `export("Rcpp.fake.fun")` to `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` to prevent the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'mypkg' in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
   undefined exports: Rcpp.fake.fun
```

Or maybe one can export directly `export("f_sample_p")`, since it is the only function. The `exportPattern` method is a shortcut. Is there a way to set this in the parameters of `Rcpp.package.skeleton` instead of manually edit the NAMESPACE? This manual edit would prevent the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'mypkg' in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: Rcpp.fake.fun
```

As a third step, I build the package in a user-defined path.

```
lib_path <- "~/R/rlib/"

install.packages("~/R/rpkg/mypkg", # where is the package
                 lib=lib_path, # where I want to build it
                 repos=NULL, # NULL because I install from local files
                 type = "source") # from the skeleton and is not a zipped tarball
```

Now the package is ready to use.

```
require("mypkg", "~/R/rlib/")
f_sample_p(1:15, 8)
# [1] 16  8  5 21  6 17 21 24
```

I generate 8 random numbers starting from a vector from 1 to 15.

As a final step, I am ready to use this function in my R code. The following is also a simplification of my actual code. This runs many times (say 100) the function `sim_function` that calls the function `f_sample_p` and it does with `lapply`.

```
library(parallel)

sim_function <- function(n){
  # define the simulation function to be used in lapply
  z <- f_sample_p(n, 8) # samples 8 elements from the vector n
  sum(z) # return the sum
}

# prepare the input: this will loop 100 times in the simulation function
x <- runif(100, 1, 10) 

# this works well in classic lapply
result <- lapply(x, sim_function)

# but it won't with parLapply
cl <- makeCluster(2)
clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c(
  "f_sample_p" # the variable list
))

result <- parLapply(cl, x, sim_function) # this generates the error
```

This last line generates the following error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: object '_mypkg_f_sample_p' not found
```

It seems that parLapply expects the function `_mypkg_f_sample_p` instead of `f_sample_p`. In fact, the call method for `f_sample_p` is the following:

```
f_sample_p

function (x, nb = 5L) 
{
    .Call(`_mypkg_f_sample_p`, x, nb)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000020e09d70448>
<environment: namespace:mypkg>
```

Actually, the exported function defined at the moment of the build has a changed name. If you look into the RcppExports.cpp (src folder) you find that it contains:

```
...
// f_sample_p
NumericVector f_sample_p(NumericVector x, int nb);
RcppExport SEXP _mypkg_f_sample_p(SEXP xSEXP, SEXP nbSEXP) {
...
}
```

Is there a way to change the export name?

If I try to include this `_mypkg_f_sample_p` into the `clusterExport()`, R would not find it in the environment:

```
clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c(
  "f_sample_p", "_mypkg_f_sample_p" # the variable list
))
```

Giving the error:

```
Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object '_mypkg_f_sample_p' not found
```

As I said, I have checked many other posts and docs but without success. I am out of ammo. Any idea?

**Edit about a month later**: Thinking about the function passed into `parLapply()`, I erroneously (as I will show further) imagined that I could cheat the function when I pass the list of variables to `sim_function`. All variables used explicitly within `sim_function` are listed in the `varlist` parameter of `clusterExport`.

For example, if this works:

```
sim_function <- function(n){
  # define the simulation function to be used in lapply
  z <- rep(n, 8) # <= I have replaced f_sample_p() with rep() 
  sum(z) # return the sum
}
```

The result will not be the same obviously, but technically it works: `clusterExport` will accept `rep()` - no question asked. Maybe, if  I can pass a wrapper for my `f_sample_p` function, I could get around the variable defined within the scope of `sim_function()`.

```
wrap_sample_p <- function(n1, n2){
  f_sample_p(n1, n2) # this is now defined outside the scope of sim_function
}
sim_function <- function(n){
  # define the simulation function to be used in lapply
  z <- wrap_sample_p(n, 8) # I pass the wrapper function
  sum(z) # return the sum
}
```

Then I call:

```
clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c(
  "wrap_sample_p" # the variable list
))
result <- parLapply(cl, x, sim_function) # this generates the following error
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "f_sample_p"
```

Yet, it seems to care not only about the scope of `sim_function` but also about the environment. And the following:

```
clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c(
  "f_sample_p", "wrap_sample_p" # the variable list
))
result <- parLapply(cl, x, sim_function) # this generates the following error
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: object '_mypkg_f_sample_p' not found
```

Still, it is looking for `_mypkg_f_sample_p`.

Comment: You need @Dirk Eddelbuettel.

Comment: This might be simple: parallel R instances probably don't know about your R package, because they don't know the library path "~/R/rlib/". You could install your package in the default library path. Alternatively `require` the R package within the loop (or use `clusterEvalQ`).